# Possible to Send Basic Auth in Link in Java

Tags: hyperlink, basic-authentication

Is it possible to send basic auth credentials in a link? I have tried http://username:password@anapi.com but it's not working (in chrome on a mac, it keeps telling me to provide APIKey, which is password in this case). I need to be able to have a user click on a link and provide these credentials, if possible.

The link is to sometimes huge files (< 1 gig). So instead of me, downloading the file in question I would like to just construct a link that points to it, and have the user download it.

It's in Java because I'm making a Java Portlet, but I can construct the link just like an html element:

```
<a href="https://username:password@google.com">Click here!</a>
```

Any advice would help,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember a specific Microsoft support article in which they explicitly dropped browser support for including passwords in URLs like this; it's probable that other browsers did too.

EDIT: [here's](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;%5BLN%5D;834489) the article.

Comment: I see, sounds like it was quite a security risk, thanks for the info!