# How to get same remote session with cURL and ajax curl request?

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl, mod-proxy

I have php site that curl's remote php app with mod rewrite proxy that uses session to store app state. Page's some php codes are loaded from remote server with mod proxy and curl (in to the center box, so no htm and head tags goes trough curl)

I used this method to save the curl remote session and it works ok:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6989705/2278155
Thank you @Scuzzy !

But my app also have couple simple ajax (not jquery, but plain httpRequest) that does not seem to share the same session than php / curl! ajax call also goes trough the same mod proxy and curl. When i made a counter, it was clear that ajax call and normal page refresh trough curl had a different sessions.

How can i make them same ? can i add some url parameter like sid= ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same Problem as you. I'm developing an application which will be accessible either via Webbrowser (WebServer1) or as an HTML5_App for iPad and Android. Because the Core of my Application is (APIServer2) I also have two different SID's.

My Login works as following:

-> Ajax Request to API Server for Login. If success, store the users SID in the database on APIServer.
-> APIServer Returns the SID to the Client, this one makes a refresh on the Page and transmitts the SID to the WebURL of WebServer1
-> WebServer1 checks if the SID is valid and found in the database. If so, select and store this user.

Now I can handle all my operations even that I've got two different SIDs.

Hope this helps!

Greetings